# Get text between two '/'s from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this: http://igrigc.com/business/spoint/Story/Secure-444

where I would like to retrieve the text "business" that is there between 2 '/'s using JavaScript. Can someone please help me out on this? Thanks.

Comment: [`str.split('/')[3]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VisioN said, you can split it up using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). This splits a string into a array based on the parameter passed. It splits the string into parts wherever it finds the string.

Here, we can use that method to split the link into different parts based on the `/`s to get to the `business` directory.

```
var str = "http://igrigc.com/business/spoint/Story/Secure-444";
var parts = str.split("/") //["http:", "", "igrigc.com", "business", "spoint", "Story", "Secure-444"]
console.log(parts[3]); //"business"
```